# How to use the Python Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Could any of you explain how exactly to use the Facebook Graph API? It makes ABSOLUTELY NO sense to me. I understand that I have to have an api key and a secret app key and I have those. I just need to know what the basics are to get the data from graph.facebook.com using Python. There are no sources ANYWHERE and its killing me. In short, how do I get to the point where I can open a url with certain parameter passed, and it actually return the data to me?

Thanks so much
Justin

Answer (score 15):

There's a library in Github for Python-Facebook integration: https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk

Basic usage

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")
```

Comment: How do you get the oauth_access_token?

Comment: You can learn more about the access token at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/ . It's a string that is generated when the user logs in.

Comment: Alright I got the access token, how do I request a page then?

Comment: @user1377480 /thread

Comment: PyCharm complains that cannot find reference to GraphAPI :/